# Plotly create_trisurf using fillter to blur

Tags: python, image, 3d, plotly, medical

I'm working 3d medical image. I'm using plotly3d to plot 3d images but the 3d image doesn't make a smooth surface. How can I use blur or anything else to solve this problem?
This is my code:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.